# How to replace part of string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, wordpress, url

i have URL in db column "guid"

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Waterproofing2.png
```

i need to change it to

```
http://example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Waterproofing2.png
```

i need to replace all URL's with

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/
```

to

```
http://example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/
```

Comment: whats the problem in update query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) function:

```
update `table` set `column`= replace (`column`, 'http://example.com/','http://example.com/blog/') where `column`like 'http://example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads%'
```

Comment: thanks, but i need to select all url's which starts http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/ and change to http://example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/

Answer (score 4):

Heya easiest way to do that is using replace function in sql

simple

```
REPLACE(YourString, ‘text to replace’, ‘replace with text’)
```

`REPLACE` performs comparisons based on the collation of the input. To perform a comparison in a specified collation, you can use `COLLATE` to apply an explicit collation to the input.

In SQL, wildcard characters are used with the SQL LIKE operator.

SQL wildcards are used to search for data within a table.

With SQL, some of the wildcards are:

```
Wildcard    Description
%   A substitute for zero or more characters
_   A substitute for a single character
```

so **Quickest Way**
    Use CONCAT:
    http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

So an example from a friend , change the following

```
styles/default/xenmoods/pants.png

styles/default/xenmoods/andrew.png

styles/default/xenmoods/rawr.png
```

to this

```
http://cdn.sociallyuncensored.com/styles/default/xenmoods/pants.png
http://cdn.sociallyuncensored.com/styles/default/xenmoods/andrew.png
http://cdn.sociallyuncensored.com/styles/default/xenmoods/rawr.png
```

CODE:

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE SET path =CONCAT('http://example.com/blog/wpcontent/uploads/', path) ... where ..etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use this query for WordPress database moves

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://olddomain.com', 'src="http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');
```