# Wordpress Migration Broken Images

Tags: mysql, wordpress, image, ftp, migration

I'm having a little issue with a Wordpress site. What I **want to do** is to migrate all the posts/news from one installation to a new one, including it's images.

So what I did, apart from reading **a lot** of tutorials, was.

**First** Download the XML that contains all the info from the posts,

**Second** Uploaded the XML to the new site, it imported the posts, categories and authors with no problems, but with no images.

**Third** I transferred the images via FTP, to the same location, with no change in the names or anything. Also, the folder has all the permissions.

**Fourth** I read that after all this is done, it's necessary to do a MySQL change, related to the "post_content" where you should change the old domain, for the new. The change is made, but nothing happens, the images are still not visible.

So.. What could be the step that can be missing? Or did I made something wrong?

This [post](http://legendofvelda.com/2012/03/13/fixing-broken-image-links-after-moving-wordpress/) has the information related to the MySQL sentence to replace the "post_content" field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what the URL is of your images? Are they still pointing to the old domain or did you do something wrong with the replace? Maybe my full query can help you, you can see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361920/how-to-replace-part-of-string-in-sql/28362337#28362337

Comment: In this particular case, I moved the posts and images to a local installation, because I'm testing this process without making a mistake. The old URL is
http://www.previsionsocial.gob.cl/subprev, and the local one is http://localhost/sps1

So the query looks like this

`UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_content = REPLACE( post_content,     'previsionsocial.gob.cl/subprev/', 'localhost/sps/' )`

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question, where are the images pointing at now? Is it the old url, or the new url? If it is the old url, your mysql replace failed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I sent the comment before it was complete.

Comment: Alright... but if you check an post of your installation, and right click on the broken image... what URL does it says it tried to load? Is that your localhost, or your old domain?

Comment: I was looking for the image in the code, and in fact **there's no broken image** or at least I'm not seeing it in the code. 

It's possible that this is due to the change of theme? The loop it's basically the same, so I think that **it should** spit the image into the post.

Comment: Also, the image gallery isn't rebuilt, no images appear at all. Is there a way to rebuild this?